# Adicionar o valor 5 no final na lista/tupla

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lista_da_tupla_a=(["0", "33", "40"], ["8", "30","9"], ["7", "0", "0"])

lista_da_tupla_a = list

lista_da_tupla_a[2] = "5"

print(lista_da_tupla_a)
```

Saída desejada: `(["0", "33","5"], ["8","30",5], ["7","0","5"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer é isso:

```
lista_da_tupla_a = (["0", "33", "40"], ["8", "30","9"], ["7", "0", "0"])
for tuplinha in lista_da_tupla_a:
    tuplinha[2] = "5"
print(lista_da_tupla_a)
```

Ou seja, você usa o `for` para percorrer cada trio e substituir o terceiro elemento por `"5"`.

Eis a saída:

```
(['0', '33', '5'], ['8', '30', '5'], ['7', '0', '5'])
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/PpWk0P)